# should I use mvvm (light) global Messaging

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light, messaging

I have some global/semi global collections.

One a schedule of timers to be added to

The other a collection representing remote computers which can have a number of actions performed on them

Currently I have one instantiated collection that I reference directly.

I was thinking of using messaging instead but doing Messenger.Default.Register seems to be not that different from using globals and not that testable(although adding or running functions on each element of a list may not be something you want to test).

Should I register it on a particular viewmodel and pass in the messenger to the viewmodel constructor instead? Or do something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using MVVM Light...

So:

If you've got two global collections basically you've got a couple of Singletons and the question is how to best integrate them into your viewmodels.

I'd treat both these things as services and wrap the class that holds them in an interface.  So:

```
public interface IRemoteComputersService
{
    void AddComputer(Computer computerToAdd);
    void RemoveComputer(Computer computerToremove);
    ReadOnlyCollection<Computer> RemoteComputers{get;}
}
```

The interface would need to be overload onto the class that manages your remote PCs

In my ViewModelLocator I'd register it:

```
public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, Design.DesignDataService>();
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IRemoteComputersService,RemoteComputersService>();
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();         
        }
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }

}
```

In my ViewModel I'd inject it into the viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel:ViewModelBase, IMyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel(IRemoteComputersService remoteComputerService)
    {
        _remoteComputerService=remoteComputerService;
    }
}
```

Under the hood the SimpleIoc will recursively resolve the dependencies for your viewmodel.  Because "MyViewModel" has a dependency on the IRemoteComputersService service it will first resolve this and then inject it into the viewmodel.

Because MVVM-Light treats each item resolved in it's container as, by default, a singleton, you're guaranteed that you'll only have one IRemoteComputersService being resolved by the SimpleIoc.

This resolves your issue - making your PCs and Timers accessible to your viewmodels in a nicer, testable way and also means you don't need to look at Messaging.